React Native : View config getter callback for component `NativeCamera` must be a function (received `undefined`)
i am trying to load native camera component on Android but always getting error from title.
This component is in local package which is linked via package json
    "react-native-native-camera": "file:lib/react-native-native-camera",

I can see my package in packages list and when i log UIManager in RN code component is there.
Here is the component code:
package com.NativeCamera

import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap
import com.facebook.react.common.MapBuilder
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp

class NativeCameraManager : SimpleViewManager<NativeCameraView>() {

    companion object {
        const val REACT_CLASS = "SmNativeCamera"
    }

    enum class Events(private val mName: String) {
        EVENT_CAMERA_READY("onCameraReady"),
        EVENT_ON_MOUNT_ERROR("onMountError"),
        EVENT_ON_RECORDING_START("onRecordingStart"),
        EVENT_ON_RECORDING_END("onRecordingEnd");

        override fun toString(): String {
            return mName
        }
    }

    override fun getName(): String {
        Log.d("NativeCameraView", "getName() called")

        return REACT_CLASS
    }

    override fun createViewInstance(c: ThemedReactContext): NativeCameraView {
        Log.d("NativeCameraView", "createViewInstance() called")

        return NativeCameraView(c)
    }

    override fun getCommandsMap(): Map<String, Int>? {
        return MapBuilder.of(
                "startRecording",
                COMMAND_START_RECORDING,
                "stopRecording",
                COMMAND_STOP_RECORDING,
                "lockFocusAndExposure",
                COMMAND_LOCK_FOCUS_AND_EXPOSURE,
                "startBeep",
                COMMAND_START_BEEP,
                "changeFacing",
                COMMAND_CHANGE_FACING
        )
    }

    override fun receiveCommand(view: NativeCameraView, commandId: Int, args: ReadableArray?) {
        when (commandId) {
            COMMAND_START_RECORDING -> view.startRecording(args)
            COMMAND_STOP_RECORDING -> view.stopRecording()
           
        }
    }


In logcat logs i can see only log from getName() function
        Log.d("NativeCameraView", "getName() called")

while
        Log.d("NativeCameraView", "createViewInstance() called")

is never called.
Any ideas
P.S. tried many things related to reset cache, gradlew clean etc etc
In logcat logs i can see only log from getName() function
        Log.d("NativeCameraView", "getName() called")

while
        Log.d("NativeCameraView", "createViewInstance() called")

is never called.
Any ideas
P.S. tried many things related to reset cache, gradlew clean etc etc
